# keith wood datepick + bootstrap modal : issue only in firefox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using Keith Wood Datepick jquery-plugin with bootstrap.
When it is attached to an input field on a bootstrap modal window, the month and year dropdowns ("select boxes") are not being opened.

This issue is only on Firefox browser.

```
Here is the JS fiddle example :: http://jsfiddle.net/suryapavan/AvSwp/1/
```

Thanks in Advance!